# How to notify application about updated config file in kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

When having configmap update, how to automatically trigger the reload of parameters by the application? Application uses POSIX signals for that.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how you are consuming the configmap values, there could be two ways in which you can reload the configmap updates into a running pod.

- If you are consuming the configs as environment variables, you can write a controller, which watches for the updates in configs and restarts your pods with new config whenever the config changes.
- If you are consuming the configmap via volumes, you can watch for file changes and notify that to your process in the container and handle the update in application. Please see https://github.com/jimmidyson/configmap-reload for example.

Comment: Restart is not an option. About the second one: why we need to watch the filesystem all the time if the kubernetes already knows that it has changed the config?

Comment: Kubernetes only changes the file that's mounted into the pod but how would your app/process know that the config has changed? So, you can watch the file and notify your process. The above Github project seems to notify your app with a `HTTP` call.

Comment: ok, so it only changes the file. I'm just trying to evaluate what it takes to do my deployment with various alternative tools. Everything has different sets of features.

Answer (score 0):

There are good solutions mentioned around here but I tried to find a solution that could be done without modifying existing deployment pipelines, etc.
Here is an example of a filebeat Daemonset from a Helm chart that reloads when the filebeat config changes.  The approach is not new: use the liveness probe to trigger a reload of the pod *from within the pod* itself.  The *postStart* calculates an md5 sum of the configmap directory; the liveness probe checks it.  That's all.

The '...' are just to cut out the cruft.  You can see that the filebeat.yml file is mounted directly into /etc and used by filebeat itself.  The configmap is mounted again, specifically for the purposes of watching the configmap contents for changes.

Once configmap is edited (or otherwise modified), it takes some time before the pod is actually restarted.  You can tweak all of that separately.

```
#apiVersion: apps/v1
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: ...-filebeat
...
      containers:
      - name: ...-filebeat
        image: "{{ .Values.filebeat.image.url }}:{{ .Values.filebeat.image.version }}"
        imagePullPolicy: "{{ .Values.filebeat.image.pullPolicy }}"
        command: [ "filebeat" ]
        args: [
          "-c", "/etc/filebeat-config/filebeat.yml",
          "-e"
        ]
        env:
...
        resources:
...
    lifecycle:
      postStart:
        exec:
          command: ["sh", "-c", "ls -LRih /etc/filebeat-config | md5sum >> /tmp/filebeat-config-md5.txt"]
    livenessProbe:
      exec:
        # Further commands can be strung to the statement e.g. calls with curl
        command:
          - sh
          - -c
          - >
            x=$(cat /tmp/filebeat-config-md5.txt);
            y=$(ls -LRih /etc/filebeat-config | md5sum);
            if [ "$x" != "$y" ]; then exit 1; fi
      initialDelaySeconds: 60
      periodSeconds: 60
    volumeMounts:
    - name: filebeat-config
      mountPath: /etc/filebeat-config
      readOnly: true
....
```